# How to calculate the percentage of different values in same column and group by month of current year?

Tags: mysql

I want to take the percentage of only SLA's in the sla_osla table and group them by all the months of current year

Here is my table

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/179518/2

I have tried the following query

```
    SELECT MONTH(service_date),((nums/(count(*)))*100) AS perc 
      FROM orders CROSS JOIN (SELECT MONTH(service_date) AS months, COUNT(*) AS 
   nums FROM orders WHERE YEAR(service_date) = year(CURRENT_DATE()) AND sla_osla = 
  'sla' 
     GROUP BY MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())) table1
     WHERE YEAR(service_date) = YEAR(current_date) AND sla_osla IN ('sla','osla')
     GROUP BY MONTH(service_date)
```

I want output like this

```
month percentage

    1       75%
    2       50%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/179518/76

This is more simple sql

`Select year(service_date), month(service_date), sum(sla_osla = "sla")/ count(*) * 100 FROM orders group by year(service_date), month(service_date)`

I've also grouped by year here.

Edit if you want the percent sign etc then use this

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/179518/82

Comment: You forgot to test for current year. Then you wouldn't need to GROUP BY the year anyways.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT month(service_date) as dmonth,count(1) 
  FROM orders where sla_osla='sla'
 group by dmonth
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/179518/129

```
SELECT MONTH(service_date) month, CONCAT(FORMAT(SUM(sla_osla='sla')/COUNT(*)*100,0),'%') percentage FROM orders WHERE YEAR(CURDATE())=YEAR(service_date) GROUP BY MONTH(service_date);
```

Comment: I want to group this by all the months of current year not by sla_osla and I need only sla percentage not sla and osla percentage

Comment: Check the fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/179518/40 have taken reference from @StackSlave answer and included the things you want. Have a look.

Comment: @PrasadWargad my sample required output is given

Comment: @stackslave the value for February should be 50 not 25 that is wrong

Comment: Fixed to your liking.